# JavaServer Faces Bean instantiation order

Tags: jsf

Are there any guarantees about the order in which JSF creates its managed beans?

My case is pretty much the following:
I have 2 beans that I use in the same page. When creating the second one, I want it to get some information from the first, e.g. in its @PostConstruct method (to avoid hitting the database).

Is there any way I can make sure the first bean is actually created before the second, so getting the data succeeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ensure this by injecting the one bean as a managed property of the other bean.

Assuming that you're already on JSF 2.0, use [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FirstBean {
    // ...
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecondBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{firstBean}")
    private FirstBean firstBean; // +setter

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // firstBean is available here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

Or when you're still on JSF 1.2, use `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>firstBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.FirstBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>secondBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.SecondBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>firstBean</property-name>
        <value>#{firstBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. (I'm pretty sure I've known that at some point in the time :))

Except this, are beans constructed in random order?

Comment: No, they are constructed in order of EL expressions in the UI component tree and they are only constructed when none is present in the desired scope yet.

Comment: How about a backing bean in session scope ? which is not associated with any UI Component in any page - used only for some internal purpose ?

Comment: @guru: it should not be a backing bean then. Use `HttpSessionListener`.